# Using fork() in C?

Tags: c, fork

I have been asked this question for homework, and am having trouble figuring it out. If anyone can help me i would really appreciate it.

What Linux library function is like a fork(), but the parent process is terminated?

Comment: There is none AFAIK, although perhaps looking up `exec` would be useful as it is often used in conjunction with `fork` (e.g. ["fork-exec"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec)).

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that whoever assigned you this homework is looking for the **[`exec()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)** family of functions,  from the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) API header [**`<unistd.h>`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h), because there is nothing else that more closely resembles the sort of functionality you describe.

The `exec()` family of functions executes a new process and replaces the currently running process address space with the newly executed process.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec):

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with
>   a new process image.

It's not exactly the same as "terminating" the parent process, but in practice it results in a similar situation where the parent process address space is erased (replaced) with the address space of the child process.

Comment: So you are saying that exec is the library function?

Answer (score 0):

> What Linux library function is like a fork(), but the parent process
>   is terminated?

The parent process should not terminate because , it must wait for the child processes to finish executing , after which they will be in a state called "zombie state", now it is the responsibility of the parent to clean up the leftovers of the child process. The parent process can terminate without cleaning up the child processes, but then, it is not a proper way to do it, as the exit status of the child processes should be collected and checked by the parent process.

Here is an example, to demonstrate , what i just said...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t cpid = 1 ;
  int status;

  cpid = fork();

  // Load a application to the child using execl() , and finish the job

  printf("Parent waiting for child to terminate\n");

  int wait_stat = waitpid(-1,&status,0);     // Parent will hang here till all child processes finish executing..
  if (wait_stat < 0)
  {
    perror("waitpid error");
    exit(-1);
  } 

  // WIFEXITED and WEXITSTATUS are macros to get exit status information, of the child process

  if (WIFEXITED (status))          
  {
  printf("Child of id %u cleaned up\n",wait_stat);
  printf("Exit status of application = %u\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
  }

}
```

Comment: The parent process can terminate, in which case `init` `wait()`s on the children.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña , true , but its best done by the parent , where the exit code of the child can be interpreted and appropriate measures can be taken

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying it's indeed possible for the parent to terminate without waiting on the child; it's not necessarily a bad practice. In some circumstances the parent might not care at all about the status of the child. In fact one strategy consists of forking twice and terminating the first child so that the original process can continue processing without caring about the status of the remaining (second) child process (as it will then be handled by `init`).

Comment: All that said, I think the OP was actually asking about `exec()`, though I agree the phrasing probably made it sound like he was actually asking about terminating a parent process.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña , yes agreed , there may be other ways to cleaning up than what i thought, but OP looking like a beginer may best stick to cleaning up in the traditional way..